# render conditional sidebar in react by roles

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to filter items in a sidebar according to roles, I tried to do a conditional render in the login submit but I think it didn't work for me, I logged in and showed the items according to role but I clicked on the sidebar and it showed everything again. it eliminated routes but it appeared in the sidebar (it clicked and "page not found" appeared) but the sidebar item did not disappear. I don't know if I should do something in the sidebar or in the routes or login.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the roles into an array and when rendering, check if the user has a specific role.
Example:

```
{ props.userRoles.indexOf("admin") >= 0? <Component/>:null}
```